# Как получить Время отклика ( response time) сервера с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, curl

Как получить Время отклика (response time) сервера с помощью PHP?

Comment: Только не сервера, а конкретной страницы: на одной странице будет три запроса к БД (или вообще ни одного), а на другой двадцать пять тяжёлых запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php. и таким вариантов

```
$ch = curl_init('http://google.com'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // Не грузим сам сайт
curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'Время запроса - ' . $info['total_time'] . ' на сайт ' . $info['url'];
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне приходится устанавливать следующие значения curl_setopt (иначе сервер понимает что робот и не отвечает):
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 

Скажите если запустить curl c такими параметрами это повлияет на время отклика страницы

Comment: Если и повлияет - то очень незначительно.